# Operator -gt and -le / Problem with negative numbers

Tags: powershell

i have the following code snippet where i change the values in a column (named G) of a csv to Y if the integer value is greater then 1 and to N if it is equal to 1 and smaller.

```
ForEach-Object {if ($_.G -gt '1') {$_.G = 'Y'} if ($_.G -le '1') {$_.G = 'N'} $_}
```

It works fine with the exception of negative numbers. I always get a Y. I don't have any idea. Example data:

F,G
item1, -58
item2, -77
item3, 562

Does anyone have an idea?

Regards, Hubertus

Comment: If you open your csv file in a text editor (*not* Excel), does it contain values like ```"abc", "-58", "xyz"``` or ```"abc", -58, "xyz"``` (i.e. does the ```-58``` have quotes around it)? It looks like it's treating your data as strings and doing string comparisons rather than numeric comparisons. You're also encouraging this by doing ```-gt '1'``` instead of ```-gt 1```...

Comment: @mclayton, when i open it in the editor the numbers are not surrounded by " ". Just the number. Have tried it with the -gt 1 instead of -g'1' same result.

Comment: @mclayton When PowerShell imports CSV, it always treats the data as strings only. It doesn't do any conversion like with JSON, regardless of quoting.

Comment: @zett42 - O_o. Learn something new every day! ```"value`r`n100" | convertfrom-csv | % { write-host $_.value.GetType() }``` -> ```System.String```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to evaluate the `$_.G` property as a number you need to specify the type as `[int]`. Example using your code:

```
    $testObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        G='-1'
    }
    
    $testObject| %{ 
    if ([int]$_.G -gt 1) 
    {
        $out = "{0} is greater than 1" -f $_.G
        Write-Host $out -ForegroundColor Green  
        [string]$_.G = "Y"              
    } 
    elseif ([int]$_.G -le 1) 
    {
        $out = "{0} is Less than 1" -f $_.G
        Write-Host $out -ForegroundColor Green   
        [string]$_.G = "N" 
    }    
}
```

Note: In order to assign `$_.G` as a string you have to change the type to `[string]`. In my opinion, I would use another property to indicate "Y/N" instead of flipping the type back and forth on the property.

Comment: thank you very much. I didnt knew that. I have changed it to the follow:
ForEach-Object {if ([int]$_.G -gt '1') {$_.G = 'Y'} if ([int]$_.G -le '1') {$_.G = 'N'} $_} 
It works, but i get an error message, that Y or N couldnt been converted to an integer value. Do i need to define the value as a string?

Comment: Now that `$_.G` is an `[int]` you will not be able to assign a string to it (`$_.G = 'Y'`). You would have to either change the type back to a `[string]` or assign it to another property. I'll update my answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

The left side of -le or -gt controls the type for both sides, int32 (integer) in this case.  You probably want an else in there, to not look at the G again after changing it.

```
'G
-1
1
2' | 
convertfrom-csv | 
ForEach-Object {
  if (1 -le $_.G) 
    {$_.G = 'Y'} 
  else
    {$_.G = 'N'} 
  $_
} 

G
-
N
Y
Y
```